# How do I get the default value of an optional parameter, using Dart's analyzer API?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I'm using [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org)'s [analyzer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) API, which allows me to introspect Dart code.

Here is some example code:

```
void soIntense(anything, {bool flag: true, int value}) {  }
```

Notice how the `flag` parameter has a default value of `true`.

How can I get the default value, assuming I have an instance of `ParameterElement`?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the best way that I found. I'm hoping there's a better way.

First, check that there is a default value:

```dart
bool hasDefaultValue = _parameter.defaultValueRange != null &&
       _parameter.defaultValueRange != SourceRange.EMPTY;
```

Then, you can use a `ParameterElement`'s `defaultValueRange`.

```
SourceRange range = _parameter.defaultValueRange;
return _parameter.source.contents.data.substring(range.offset, range.end);
```

In english:

*Get the parameter element's Source's content's data's substring.*